# How do I prevent decimal values from being truncated to 2 places on save using the EntityFramework 4.1 CodeFirst?

Tags: c#, decimal, ef-code-first

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Entity Framework Code First: decimal precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504660/entity-framework-code-first-decimal-precision)

I'm using Linq-to-Entities with the EntityFramework 4.1 Code First system. All of my `decimal` properties are being truncated to two decimal places on save. I can examine the object being modified and can see in the debugger that is has the right number of decimal places and I can hard code the value in the database to show that it can accept the right number of decimal places [in this case, `decimal(4,3)`]. But when I save the value, it never saves it correctly, but instead truncates `decimal` values to two decimal places. I haven't been able to find a class in `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` that allows you to specify precision. The class (sanitized), for reference is:

```
public class Metrics
{
    public decimal? PPM { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Metrics> Metrics { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Metrics>().Property(x => x.PPM).HasPrecision(4, 3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where we need to add this class ?

Comment: this the fine way i found, @Ahmed you can place it in the ApplicationDbContext or the context which you are using for database models