# Setting up precision on columns. Entity Framework CF

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, precision

How do I specify decimal precision when creating a table column in Code First Entity Framework 4.2?

Comment: title and question text are very different and unrelated, aspnet and aspnet-mvc tags are missing...

Answer (score 1):

Try using this approach http://geekswithblogs.net/danemorgridge/archive/2010/12/20/ef4-code-first-control-unicode-and-decimal-precision-scale-with.aspx

or

The simplier one:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Metrics> Metrics { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Metrics>().Property(x => x.PPM).HasPrecision(4, 3);
    }
}
```

taken from [How do I prevent decimal values from being truncated to 2 places on save using the EntityFramework 4.1 CodeFirst?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629263/how-do-i-prevent-decimal-values-from-being-truncated-to-2-places-on-save-using-t)

Good luck!