# Set decimal(16, 3) for a column in Code First Approach in EF4.3

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, sql-types

How can I do this :

```
private decimal _SnachCount;
[Required]
[DataType("decimal(16 ,3)")]
public decimal SnachCount
{
    get { return _SnachCount; }
    set { _SnachCount = value; }
}

private decimal _MinimumStock;
[Required]
[DataType("decimal(16 ,3)")]
public decimal MinimumStock
{
    get { return _MinimumStock; }
    set { _MinimumStock = value; }
}

private decimal _MaximumStock;
[Required]
[DataType("decimal(16 ,3)")]
public decimal MaximumStock
{
    get { return _MaximumStock; }
    set { _MaximumStock = value; }
}
```

After generating the database by this part of my model , these three columns type are decimal(18,2),why?
what is this code error? how can i do that ?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

The `DataType` Attribute is a Validation Attribute. You need to do that using the ModelBuilder.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MyClass> MyClass;
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyClass>().Property(x => x.SnachCount).HasPrecision(16, 3);
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyClass>().Property(x => x.MinimumStock).HasPrecision(16, 3);
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyClass>().Property(x => x.MaximumStock).HasPrecision(16, 3);
    }
}
```

Comment: the second one does not work right , any way ,thank you , you helped me and your answer accepted, please omit the second idea in your answer,thanks

Comment: Additional note: after you override the `OnModelCreating` method (as shown above), if you then run the `add-migration` command in the Package Manager Console, it will recognize your new code and will add a migration to correctly alter the columns.

Comment: Is this now also possible to do through data annotations using the column attribute like [Column(TypeName = "decimal(16,3)")] ?

Comment: modelBuilder.Entity<MyClass>().Property(x => x.X).HasColumnType("decimal(16,3)") will works fine with the EF Core 3.1.3.

Comment: Yeah, because it would be way too easy if there was a way to do it using data annotations.

Comment: This is what i wanted !, yes when i add migration after placing this code i got the change recognized, i do not have to write any plain SQL

Answer (score 35):

You can modify all decimal propreties in database. In your DBContext in method OnModelCreating add line:

```
modelBuilder.Properties<decimal>().Configure(c => c.HasPrecision(18, 3));
```

Comment: Saved my day!! So long was I trying around in the database tables but this is the solution. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 22):

This is copied from the answer I posted to the same question over here; https://stackoverflow.com/a/15386883/1186032.

---

I had a nice time creating an Custom Attribute for this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class DecimalPrecisionAttribute : Attribute
{
    public DecimalPrecisionAttribute(byte precision, byte scale)
    {
        Precision = precision;
        Scale = scale;

    }

    public byte Precision { get; set; }
    public byte Scale { get; set; }

}
```

using it like this

```
[DecimalPrecision(20,10)]
public Nullable<decimal> DeliveryPrice { get; set; }
```

and the magic happens at model creation with some reflection

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    foreach (Type classType in from t in Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(DecimalPrecisionAttribute)).GetTypes()
                                   where t.IsClass && t.Namespace == "YOURMODELNAMESPACE"
                                   select t)
     {
         foreach (var propAttr in classType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).Where(p => p.GetCustomAttribute<DecimalPrecisionAttribute>() != null).Select(
                p => new { prop = p, attr = p.GetCustomAttribute<DecimalPrecisionAttribute>(true) }))
         {

             var entityConfig = modelBuilder.GetType().GetMethod("Entity").MakeGenericMethod(classType).Invoke(modelBuilder, null);
             ParameterExpression param = ParameterExpression.Parameter(classType, "c");
             Expression property = Expression.Property(param, propAttr.prop.Name);
             LambdaExpression lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda(property, true,
                                                                      new ParameterExpression[]
                                                                          {param});
             DecimalPropertyConfiguration decimalConfig;
             if (propAttr.prop.PropertyType.IsGenericType && propAttr.prop.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
             {
                 MethodInfo methodInfo = entityConfig.GetType().GetMethods().Where(p => p.Name == "Property").ToList()[7];
                 decimalConfig = methodInfo.Invoke(entityConfig, new[] { lambdaExpression }) as DecimalPropertyConfiguration;
             }
             else
             {
                 MethodInfo methodInfo = entityConfig.GetType().GetMethods().Where(p => p.Name == "Property").ToList()[6];
                 decimalConfig = methodInfo.Invoke(entityConfig, new[] { lambdaExpression }) as DecimalPropertyConfiguration;
             }

             decimalConfig.HasPrecision(propAttr.attr.Precision, propAttr.attr.Scale);
        }
    }
}
```

the first part is to get all classes in the model (my custom attribute is defined in that assembly so i used that to get the assembly with the model)

the second foreach gets all properties in that class with the custom attribute, and the attribute itself so i can get the precision and scale data

after that i have to call

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MODEL_CLASS>().Property(c=> c.PROPERTY_NAME).HasPrecision(PRECITION,SCALE);
```

so i call the modelBuilder.Entity() by reflection and store it in the entityConfig variable
then i build the "c => c.PROPERTY_NAME" lambda expression

After that, if the decimal is nullable i call the

```
Property(Expression<Func<TStructuralType, decimal?>> propertyExpression)
```

method (i call this by the position in the array, it's not ideal i know, any help will be much appreciated)

and if it's not nullable i call the

```
Property(Expression<Func<TStructuralType, decimal>> propertyExpression)
```

method.

Having the DecimalPropertyConfiguration i call the HasPrecision method.

Comment: This really should be part of EF ... shame really, its an elegant solution, but it will make a mess of OnModelCreation

Comment: https://github.com/richardlawley/EntityFrameworkAttributeConfig by http://stackoverflow.com/users/163495/richard helps make it much cleaner 
you can see his comment in my answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504660/decimal-precision-and-scale-in-ef-code-first/15386883#15386883

Answer (score 13):

So, what I got working for me is this:

```
public class RestaurantItemEntity : BaseEntity
{
    [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR(128)")]
    [StringLength(128)]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }


    [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR(1024)")]
    [StringLength(1024)]
    public string Description { get; set; }


    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(16,2)")]
    [Required]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }


    [Required]
    public RestaurantEntity Restaurant { get; set; }
}
```

This is EF Code first for .NET core.

Comment: Just FYI, EF 6 will give a runtime exception if you include precision in the value for TypeName property of the ColumnAttribute. EF Core, on the other hand, demands it if you use that property.

Answer (score 2):

You can also set the precision of decimals using the code-first model mapping approach like this:

```
public class MyEntityMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<MyEntity>
{
    public MyEntityMapping()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.Id);
        Property(x => x.Id).IsRequired();
        // .HasPrecision(precision, scale)
        // 'precision' = total number of digits stored,
        // regardless of where the decimal point falls 
        // 'scale' = number of decimal places stored
        Property(x => x.DecimalItem).IsRequired().HasPrecision(16, 6);
    }
}
```