# Migration results in "Sequence contains no elements" error

Tags: entity-framework

I created a model with 3 classes using table-per-hierarchy inheritance, and with 2 foreign keys that self reference the hierarchy table.

I have a `BaseProperty` class with a self referencing key `CloneID` and navigation property `Clone`:

```
public class BaseProperty
{
   public int ID {get; set; }

   public int? CloneID {get; set; }

   public BaseProperty Clone {get; set; }

   //If I add this code, when I use Add-Migration - 
   //Sequence contains no elements error
   //public int? TriggeredCloneID {get; set;}
}
```

I have a `Property` class that inherits `BaseProperty` and has a foreign key `BlockID` and a `Block` navigation property.

```
public class Property : BaseProperty
{
   public int? BlockID { get; set; }

   public Block { get; set; }
}
```

I have a `Block` class that inherits `BaseProperty` and has a `Properties` navigation property:

```
public class Block: BaseProperty
{  
   public ICollection<Property> Properties { get; set; }

   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
   public int? ComputedNumberOfProperties { get; set; }
}
```

Note that the `Block` property in the `Property` class is also self referencing because both `Property` and `Block` inherit `BaseProperty` and I am using table-per-hierarchy inheritance.

It has been working and is in a production system with live data. Now I want to add a field (just a standard `int?` property) to the base class and I get a "Sequence contains no elements" error when I add a migration.

I found the open issue at https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/569, so 
I tried the workaround described and removed the self-referencing keys and navigation properties, but that migration failed with the same error. I now appear to be completely skewered...

Comment: Could you post code that is causing that error?

Comment: If you don't add any properties at all, and just try creating a new blank migration, does that work as expected?

Comment: @ChrisCurtis yes migrations are working normally for changes in other classes. After much trial and error, I've actually managed to get it working. There was also a database computed field in the `Block` class. Removing that (as well as self referencing properties) let me run migrations. I intend to experiment a little with the problem with a view to providing code that replicates the problem. Then I will post it here

Comment: Hi @Colin, you can post an answer to your own question for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was also a database computed field in the Block class. Removing that (as well as self referencing properties) let me run a migration.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well, I tried to change a type from `ComicImage` to `ComicMediaFile`... I wasn't careful to change the variable names so I ended up with

```
List<ComicMediaFile> ComicImages; // and after I changed this variable name to ComicMediaFiles... it worked... I don't know why.
```