# EF Code First Add-Migration “Sequence contains no matching element”

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I am new here. I have a problem about EF Code first Migration.I have database but i want to create new database. I added new entites(Ax_Account and Ax_TaxGroup etc.) but it throws "Sequence contains no matching element" when i try to run "Add-Migration NewDatabase". How can i fix it?

**Exception :**

```
PM> Add-Migration NewColumnsForProduct
System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.OSpaceTypeFactory.CreateAndAddNavigationProperty(StructuralType cspaceType, StructuralType ospaceType, NavigationProperty cspaceProperty)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.OSpaceTypeFactory.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<TryFindNavigationProperties>b__16()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.CodeFirstOSpaceLoader.LoadTypes(EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, ObjectItemCollection objectItemCollection)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.DbDatabaseMappingExtensions.ToMetadataWorkspace(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.CodeFirstCachedMetadataWorkspace.Create(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbModel.Compile()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ForceOSpaceLoadingForKnownEntityTypes()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter.get_ObjectContext()
   at Master_Database_Project.Contexts.MasterDbContext..ctor() in C:\Users\Emre.dereli\source\repos\ProductCatalog\Master Database Project\Contexts\MasterDbContext.cs:line 52
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContextInfo.CreateInstance()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContextInfo..ctor(Type contextType, DbProviderInfo modelProviderInfo, AppConfig config, DbConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Func`1 resolver)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration, DbContext usersContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState, Boolean calledByCreateDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.MigrationScaffolder..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration migrationsConfiguration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.RunCore()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
Sequence contains no matching element
```

**Ax_Account.cs**

```
[Table("Ax_Account")]

public class Ax_Account
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string NameEnglish { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public static void OnModelCreating (DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
    var e = modelBuilder.Entity<Ax_Account>();
    e.HasKey(x => x.Id);
    e.Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("id").HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    e.Property(x => x.Number).HasColumnName("number").HasMaxLength(50);
    e.Property(x => x.Name).HasColumnName("name").HasMaxLength(250);
    e.Property(x => x.NameEnglish).HasColumnName("name_english").HasMaxLength(250);
    }

}
```

**DbContext.cs**

```
public class MasterDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Language> Languages { get; set; }

        public DbSet<ProductDetailsByCountry> ProdDetailsByCountry { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProductDetailsByLanguage> ProdDetailsByLanguage { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Dimension> ProductCategories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<DimensionType> DimensionTypes { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Ax_Account> Ax_Accounts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Ax_TaxGroup> Ax_TaxGroups { get; set; }
        public DbSet<DefectedProcessOrderLineServiceType> DefectedProcessOrderLineServiceTypes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<EquipmentType> EquipmentTypes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<InsuranceTerm> InsuranceTerms { get; set; }
        public DbSet<InvoiceAlgorithmType> InvoiceAlgorithmTypes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<InvoiceProductGroup> InvoiceProductGroups { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProductType> ProductTypes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PurchasingGroup> PurchasingGroups { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Specification> Specifications { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SpecificationDetailsByCountry> SpecificationDetailsByCountries { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SpecificationDetailsByLanguage> SpecificationDetailsByLanguages { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TimeAdjustmentType> TimeAdjustmentTypes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Unit> Units { get; set; }
        public DbSet<VehicleType> VehicleTypes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<WebBufferOfferLine> WebBufferOfferLines { get; set; }


        static MasterDbContext ()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new MasterContextInitializer());
        }
        public MasterDbContext() : base("ProductCatalogDb")
        {
            var objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;
            // Update Last Changed fields for Product, DetailsByCountry, DetailsByLanguage when row is Added or Modified
            objContext.SavingChanges += (sender, args) => {
                var now = DateTimeOffset.Now;
                foreach (var entry in this.ChangeTracker.Entries<Product>()) {
                    if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified || entry.State == EntityState.Added) {
                        entry.Entity.LastChangedDatetime = now;
                    }
                }
                foreach (var entry in this.ChangeTracker.Entries<ProductDetailsByCountry>()) {
                    if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified || entry.State == EntityState.Added) {
                        entry.Entity.LastChangedDatetime = now;
                    }
                }
                foreach (var entry in this.ChangeTracker.Entries<ProductDetailsByLanguage>()) {
                    if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified || entry.State == EntityState.Added) {
                        entry.Entity.LastChangedDatetime = now;
                    }
                }
                this.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
            };
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {

            Product.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            Country.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            Language.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            User.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            ProductDetailsByCountry.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            ProductDetailsByLanguage.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            Dimension.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            DimensionType.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            Ax_Account.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            Ax_TaxGroup.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            DefectedProcessOrderLineServiceType.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            EquipmentType.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            InsuranceTerm.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            InvoiceAlgorithmType.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            InvoiceProductGroup.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            ProductType.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            PurchasingGroup.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            Specification.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            SpecificationDetailsByCountry.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            SpecificationDetailsByLanguage.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            TimeAdjustmentType.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            Unit.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            VehicleType.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            WebBufferOfferLine.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12500625/entity-framework-migrations-error-sequence-contains-no-elements

Comment: First try if the model is correct by testing it without migrations, for example in a console application using context.Database.Create. Also, off-topic, I would use EntityTypeConfiguration classes instead of this somewhat outlandish `OnModelCreating` in each entity class.

Comment: It will really help to resolve the issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12500625/entity-framework-migrations-error-sequence-contains-no-elements