# Truncation Occurs on System.Decimal to Oracle's Float when using Entity Framework 5 to Oracle 11g/12c

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework-5

I am using Entity Framework 5 code first to talk to an Oracle 11g or 12c database (I've verified the problem in both versions). The Oracle field is a `FLOAT` type while the field in my POCO is a `decimal`. I'm using `decimal` because I need my decimal places to be accurate up to 5 digits.

When I save my entity, the resulting record in the database always rounds the value to 2 decimal places.

I have verified through a database tool (Toad) that the column will support precision of 5. I cannot change the data type in the database due to backwards compatibility. I have found that using a `double` does not have the same problem. But `double` is notorious for giving inexact numbers, especially when multiple mathematical operations are performed.

Does anyone know why a `decimal` value would be truncated? I am using the Oracle data provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3504660/468215) provided by @Grant in the comments above provided the answer. I will paraphrase here. The default mapping for a `decimal` value is to an Oracle `DECIMAL(18,2)`. This is why it was rounding to two decimal places. In order to change the default behavior, you have to add a statement in the `OnModelCreating` override inside the Context class. (In EF6 you can change the convention for all of the `decimal` fields at once as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27418286/468215).)

### Change `Decimal` Mapping for a Particular `Decimal` Field

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    //...

    modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().Property(x => x.MyProperty).HasPrecision(18, 5);

    //...
}
```

Comment: this is great. Thanks