# Entity Framework currency with 3 decimal places

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

In asp.net 5+ using EF6 with code first, how do I store a decimal value with 3 decimal points?

Ie, my field needs to be able to store 272.724

Currently I have:

```
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
[DisplayName("Report Fee")]
public decimal ReportFee { get; set; }
```

I've tried adding:

```
[Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,3)")]
```

But I get the error:

```
The store type 'decimal(18,3)' could not be found in the SqlServer provider manifest
```

Comment: entity framework core 2?

Comment: Sorry, should be EF6.

Comment: STORE, to be used for a future calculation

Comment: That is still a very suspect requirement, rounding should be done where and when needed, and that is not in storage.

Comment: Just use `DataFormatString = "{0:c3}")`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try with Custom Conventions. To set decimal precision:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Properties<decimal>().Configure(config => config.HasPrecision(18, 3));
}
```

Comment: Doesnt this apply to ALL decimals though?  I only need it for the one field

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032919/set-decimal16-3-for-a-column-in-code-first-approach-in-ef4-3