# How to specify MySQL decimal precision and scale with Fluent API?

Tags: c#, mysql, ef-code-first

I'm trying to use MySQL Connector/Net 6.4.4 with EF 4.1 to generate a MySQL 5.5 decimal(19,4) column using the following code:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Payment>().Property(x => x.Amount).IsRequired().HasColumnType("decimal").HasPrecision(19, 4);
}
```

But a decimal(10,0) column is generated.  Am I missing something, or is this not supported by Connector/Net?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework Code First: decimal precision](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504660/entity-framework-code-first-decimal-precision)

Comment: The answer in the other post was to use HasPrecision(), which you can see I'm already using.  This probably works for SQL Server, but it is not working for MySQL.