# I want to save 3 decimal place value to SQL Server 2005 from ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-4

I have to set 3 decimal place in SQL Server 2005.i can set it from only model part .But In sql server set datatype of Salary is decimal.

When I set like

```
public decimal Salary { get; set; }
```

It want to save the database like 21000.000 not 21000. If I put 30000.75,then it would be saved to 30000.750.

Comment: If you're using EF, [set the precision](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504660/entity-framework-code-first-decimal-precision-and-scale) but otherwise ... just present it with as many decimal places as you need.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to solve your problem is to set the `Salary` datatype to `decimal(18, 3)`. So even if you insert a value `30000.75123` only the first three decimal digits will be saved - `30000.750`. If you insert a whole number `21000` then the value in the database will be `21000.000`.

Answer (score 0):

Even me faced this problem , one thing you can do with before sending to the database you will have to convert the value into 3 decimal places . you can do this by -

```
txtsalary.Text = String.Format("{0:0.000}", Salary);
```

or

```
decimal Salary ;

if (Decimal.TryParse(txtsalary.Text, out Salary )) // Returns true on valid input, on top of converting your string to decimal.
{
    // ... code that is doing stuff with the decimal value ...

    txtsalary.Text = String.Format("{0:0.000}", Salary );
}
else
{
    // do your error handling here.
}
```

Comment: How can i set this in mvc.what will be the change i can do in model class

Comment: [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n3}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public decimal Amount { get; set; }

Comment: its only for display.But i want to save the entered value to database as a 3 decimal place value

Comment: add this  ApplyFormatInEditMode = true , it works in edit mode too .