# Changed Decimal Precision in MVC is not storing values properly in database tables

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I m working in MVC 4 architecture project .There was a requirement for me to store certain values in 6 digits precision .So i changed the default decimal precision and scale i.e.from (18,2) to (18,6).

Problem :
Whenever i try to store the 6 digit value into the database table with new precision and scale.it stores the actual value till 2 digits scale after that the original value is replaced by 4 zeroes.

for eg:if the real value is 43.234567...the value stored in the database is 43.230000.
i m adding values to database through automation script.
Manual entry to database works fine .i mean it stores 6 digit precision value without adding zeroes.

I Changed the default decimal precision and scale through migrations.
So i don't understand where im going wrong .what is the problem here.Please help me.

Database used is SQL Server 2008

Comment: you should find answer here..
This seems to be EF issue, not MVC
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504660/entity-framework-code-first-decimal-precision-and-scale