# Parameter value is out of range in Entity Framework (DB first)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, decimal

In SQL, I have a decimal column:

[image]

Which I've mapped to an entity property in my edmx:

[image]

Frustratingly, I get an error when trying to save a value that *does* lie in this range:

```
Parameter value '164.2640000000' is out of range
```

Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening? The answers in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504660/entity-framework-code-first-decimal-precision-and-scale?rq=1) are not much help, as I'm not using code first.

Comment: Can you get a value like 164.2640000000 *from* the DB? What is the highest scale value you can get from it?

Comment: Chance of any mixup of cultures? Maybe the value is interpreted as `1642640000000`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oddly, doing another 'update from database' solved this issue.

Comment: Having the same issue with EF5, update from database. Don't see any poco classes changes, but the problem is gone.