# Inserting a decimal into sql cause inserting a zero number Instead of a decimal number near zero

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-ctp5

During insert a float number like 0.0001 into sql from my code, the result is a 0.0000 in database. here is definition of my table column:

```
decimal(20,15)
```

Here is the definition of class field:

```
public decimal Rate {get ; set; }
```

How can I solve this problem?

I am using EF Code first approach like this:

```
Class1 obj = new Class1();
obj.Rate = 0.000001;
ClassDbSet.Add(obj);
DbContext.SaveChange();
```

Comment: Can you show the code that is actually inserting the value into your DB.

Comment: More info on the database server you are using might be helpful.

Comment: Also show how you are retrieving/displaying this value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have be encounter with this issue long time ago. Add this method (if not exists) into you DbContext :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     modelBuilder.Entity<Class1>().Property(rec => rec.Rate).HasPrecision(20, 15);
}
```

when you declare a variable like this in EF and do not mention any thing about how many precision the float number have , so EF Engine accept the default value (decimale(18,2))

Answer (score 1):

If you are using EF 4.1 or above override the OnModelCreating method and specify Precision for decimal column in EF. See ([Decimal precision and scale in EF Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504660/decimal-precision-and-scale-in-ef-code-first)) post.

```
public class EFDbContext : DbContext
{
   protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
       modelBuilder.Entity<Class1>().Property(object => object.Rate).HasPrecision(20,15);

       base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
   }
}
```