# entity framework remove the decimal point

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, xaml

I have a One Record in Database

```
ItemID Price
1       10.50
```

If in wpf i select en-Us culutre then entity Framework Fetch

```
ItemID Price
1       10.50
```

But when i change the culture with es-Es then my entity framewok fetch

```
ItemID Price
1       105
```

but when i change the culture to es-Es then my desire output is

```
   ItemID Price
    1       10,5
```

what is the problem in my entity framework

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504660/decimal-precision-and-scale-in-ef-code-first

Comment: i already see this link but i already define decimal point

Comment: try to change culture to fr-Fr, that's the 2 cents that I can think of

Comment: but my client only knows spanish

Comment: Is Price declared as decimal, float or did you declare it as string/varchar? In SqlDecimal there are some "." hardcoded in it. I don't know the impact in your case but you can find different posts about it.