# Decimal Precision Lost when saved to DB, C#. I am using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

My model

```
public class Hotel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Hotel Name")]
    public string HotelName {get;set;}
    [Required]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N6}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [RegularExpression(@"\d{1,10}(\.\d{1,6})", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Latitude")]
    public Decimal Latitude { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N6}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [RegularExpression(@"\d{1,10}(\.\d{1,6})", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Longitude")]
    public Decimal Longitude { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"\d{10,20}", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Number")]    
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

}
```

The problem is with Latitude and Longitude. Their format in SQL Server DB is decimal(11, 6). So when i give the values Latitude = 41.32056 and Longitude = 19.805542 in the create from, i debug and see that the model is built correctly

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Hotel hotel)
{
    try
    {
        // TODO: Add insert logic here
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Hotels.Add(hotel);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

but the value stored in DB is Latitude = 41.320000 and Longitude = 19.800000. It should be Latitude = 41.32056 and Longitude = 19.805542.
**What am I missing.**

My DbContext class looks like this

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }        


        public DbSet<Hotel> Hotels { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Notification> Notifications { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Audit> Audit { get; set; }      

    }
```

I have never used DbModelBuilder. **Do I have to change my DbContext class?**

Comment: can you post the code of your model builder? and what is the column type in the db?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504660/decimal-precision-and-scale-in-ef-code-first

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**UPDATE**
With regards to your update - you need to add the following to your **ApplicationDbContext**:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Hotel>().Property(x => x.Longitude).HasPrecision(11, 6);
    }
```

Look here

> [Decimal precision and scale in EF Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504660/decimal-precision-and-scale-in-ef-code-first)

Comment: this shouldn't be an answer but a duplicate question flag.

Comment: Thanks a lot. After adding that to my  ApplicationDbContext I did a migration from Package Manager Console with Update-Database -Force command. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

Try adding a mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Hotel>().Property(x => x.Longitude).HasPrecision(11, 6);
```