# Very odd C# sql db decimal issue

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database, visual-studio-2019, .net-5, database-project

So i'm seeing some very odd behaviour that i can't work out what's going wrong and hoping someone can help. Originally i was seeing this in a bigger application with lots of values, but i've stripped it down to a simple example.

Test code:

```
[Test]
public void DecimalIssue()
{
    decimal decimalValueToSet = 0.00003110M;
    var modelToAdd = new TestModel { Value = decimalValueToSet };
    TestModel addedEntity = _db.Add(modelToAdd);
    int idToUse = addedEntity.Id;
    decimal? addedValue1 = addedEntity.Value;
    //int idToUse = 1;

    TestModel entity = _db.GetById(idToUse);
    decimal? value1 = entity.Value; // Sometimes value1 is 0.00000000 and sometimes it's 0.00003110
    decimal value2 = entity.Value.Value;
    decimal? value3 = Convert.ToDecimal(entity.Value);
    double value4 = Convert.ToDouble(entity.Value);
    decimal? value5 = decimalValueToSet;

    entity.Value = decimalValueToSet;
    TestModel updatedEntity = _db.Update(entity);
    decimal? updatedValue = updatedEntity.Value;

    TestModel newEntity = _db.GetById(idToUse);
    decimal? newValue = newEntity.Value;
}
```

Steps to reproduce issue:

1. Start by adding the table through the SQL Database Project and VS schema comparison
2. Run the test to add the value to the db. Everything looks correct when debugging the test
3. Check the db table in SSMS. The value shows as 0.00000000
4. Run the same test, but comment out the add section and uncomment idToUse = 1

- Now I'm seeing odd code issues, like entity.Value is 0.00003110, but value1 - value4 are all 0.00000000, but updatedValue and newValue are correct.
- The DB value is still 0.00000000 after the test finishes

5. Directly update the DB value in SSMS to 0.00003110. Run the test again and now everything is correct in the test and the DB value in SSMS is correct afterwards
6. Adding a new value acts the same as the first did
7. Delete the table and create it again and everything is back to square 1

Environment details:

- SQL Database Project - DB Schema updated through a VS schema comparison
- Azure SQL Database
- .net 5
- EF6
- VS 2019 - 16.9.4
- SSMS - 18.9.1

Not sure if this will help, but most values i add show as 0.00000000 in SSMS, but some values show differently. If for example i instead use 0.50516090M, then it shows in SSMS as 0.50000000.

Model:

```
[Table("Test")]
public class TestModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal? Value { get; set; }
}
```

DB schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test] (
    [Id]    INT              IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Value] DECIMAL (12, 8)  NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Test] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Comment: Decimal precision issues are often due to a mismatch in the model (wrong scale and precision) or else parameter type inference (by default decimals will be passed with the highest possible number of digits, which sounds like a great idea but really isn't, as even the simplest calculation can then cause them to lose precision in the fractional digits). There is a bit of an impedance mismatch here in that C# `decimal`s are variable precision, but T-SQL's `DECIMAL` types are fixed precision.

Comment: @JeroenMostert That looks like an answer to me ;-)

Comment: It is not, as the question contains too few details to confirm if this is what's going on (there's no code for the DB layer or the database schema). It's just my best guess and I hope the OP can use it to dig deeper.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention that the db column is set as: "[Value] DECIMAL (12, 8)  NULL"

Comment: And the model Value is just "public decimal? Value { get; set; }"

Comment: I've just updated the question with the model and db schema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @JeroenMostert for kinda pointing me in the right direction.
I did some more digging and found [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35037139/14248375) that has the answer i was looking for, which is to do the following:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<TestModel>().Property(x => x.Value).HasPrecision(12, 8);
}
```

I'm very surprised I've never come across this issue before!