# How to change the precision and the scale of decimal globally through code first?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

According to this answer:[Decimal precision and scale in EF Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7769162/418343)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Class>().Property(object => object.property).HasPrecision(12, 10);
```

I can change the decimal precision and scale for specific property in specific entity .

---

But i wonder how to change it globally , i mean change all the decimal attributes  to specific precision and scale because i have tons of them in different entities.

Comment: Did you look at any of the other answers on the linked question? Looks like your question is already answered, set a new convention to be used in all entity models.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [DbModelBuilder.Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbmodelbuilder.properties(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Properties%60%601) method:

> Begins configuration of a lightweight convention that applies to all primitive properties of the specified type in the model.

like this:

```
modelBuilder.Properties<decimal>().Configure(p => p.HasPrecision(12, 10));
```