# Set decimal precision for query result object

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-2.1

I have a class supplied to me via Nuget. I don't have the source.

```
 public class SpecialProductResult
  {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public decimal SpecialPercent {get;set;}
  }
```

I want to populate a list of SpecialProductResult from a stored procedure

So in my DbContext I have

```
public DbQuery<SpecialProductDto> SpecialProducts { get; set; }
```

I populate the list using

```
var specialProducts =   connect.SpecialProducts.FromSql("spGetSpecialProducts").ToList()
```

In the error log I see messages like

> No type was specified for the decimal column ‘“SpecialPercent”’ on entity
>   type ‘“SpecialProductResult”’. This will cause values to be silently
>   truncated if they do not fit in the default precision and scale.
>   Explicitly specify the SQL server column type that can accommodate all
>   the values using ‘ForHasColumnType()’.

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504660/decimal-precision-and-scale-in-ef-code-first) and wanted to try

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SpecialProductResult>().Property(o => o.GoldPercent).HasPrecision(18,4)
```

But there is no property .HasPrecision

What should I try?

[Update]

I tried Ivan Stoev's answer but received a runtime error

```
The entity type 'SpecialProductResult' cannot be added to the model because a query type with the same name already exists
```

Comment: _GoldPercent_ obviously is wrong, no? Then instead of _HasPrecision()_ try _HasColumnType("decimal(18.4)")_ as the error message suggests. Alternatively, instead of using the fluent api, you could use property attribute _[Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,4)")]_

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Currently EF Core does not provide database independent way of specifying the numeric type precision and scale (similar to EF6 `HasPrecision`).

The only way to do that is to use [HasColumnType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalpropertybuilderextensions.hascolumntype?view=efcore-2.1) and specify the database specific type. If you need to support different databases, you have to use `if` statements and different `HasColumnType` for each database type.

For SqlServer, it would be

```
modelBuilder.Query<SpecialProductResult>()
    .Property(o => o.GoldPercent)
    .HasColumnType("decimal(18,4)");
```

Comment: In EF5 I tried `.HasColumnType()` and I tried `HasPrecision()`, but the warning is still displaying in the log file. How do I make the warning go away?

Comment: @PeetBrits Both should work (an do work in my tests). e.g. `.HasPrecision(18, 4)`

Comment: As @PeetBrits stated, the error isn't going away for me even in EF7.  The only thing that works is adding the `[Precision()]` attribute on the class property.

Comment: @PoorInRichfield Not sure what you both are doing, definitely `.HasPrecision(18, 4)` removes the warning. With OP example (which now should be `DbSet`, no more `QbQuery`), the full config is `modelBuilder.Entity<SpecialProductResult>().HasNoKey().Property(e => e.SpecialPercent).HasPrecision(18, 4);` And the warning is gone.

Comment: @IvanStoev I've given up on this one. I have `entityBuilder.Property(t => t.EntryNumber).HasColumnName("MY_COLUMN").IsRequired().HasColumnType("decimal(28, 0)").UseHiLo("MY_SEQ")` where `entityBuilder` = `EntityTypeBuilder<MyType>` but no success. And yes everything is `DbSet`.

Comment: The code works but the warning never goes away.

Answer (score 21):

```
public class Part
{
    public Guid PartId { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,4)")] // <--
    public decimal Size { get; set; }
}
```

[source](http://jameschambers.com/2019/06/No-Type-Was-Specified-for-the-Decimal-Column/)

Answer (score 4):

Since EF Core 2.0 there is IEntityTypeConfiguration. In case you are using that approach, you can solve it as follows:

```
class PartConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Part>
{
  public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Part> builder){
    
     builder.Property(c => c.PartId);
     builder.Property(c => c.Number);
     builder.Property(c => c.Size)
            .HasPrecision(18, 4) <-- Use Either This
            .HasColumnType("decimal(18,4)"); <-- Or this
  }
}

...
// OnModelCreating
builder.ApplyConfiguration(new PartConfiguration());
```

For more information about using the ModelBuilder please refer to [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/)