# Decimal in form does not save, but db accepts same input manually

Tags: html, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In my form I have a field to edit/create a decimal value.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.prijs)
```

In my model, this property is declared as:

```
[Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")]
[Display(Name = "Prijs")]
public decimal? prijs { get; set; }
```

Whatever I put in there, 12.5 or 12,5 or even 12.00 or 12,00 does not get accepted.
Only "12" passes OK
When I input in the DB manually "12,5" it saves without problems.

When I view the data in another view, I see the decimal value correctly.

What's happening here?

Answer (score 0):

remove `[Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")]` and try again.

Comment: Which database you are connecting? Could you share sample code where insertion takes place in your context?

Comment: SqlServer But as stated, SQL server in itself does not have a problem with this. I guess it's a pure EF6 issue.

Comment: You might need to update your visual studio by running installer or update nugget library. Also try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504660/decimal-precision-and-scale-in-ef-code-first. It may help when you define precision point using Fluent API for entity framework.