# Is there a way to iterate through entites of the same type in a context in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I will likely have dozens of decimal properties in my model, and I set the precision in OnModelCreating like so:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Models.MyModel>()
                    .Property(x => x.MyProp)
                    .HasPrecision(18, 2);
```

But it's already getting out of hand with the length, so I was wondering if there was a way to iterate through every decimal in my context and set the precision (18,2)?

Comment: Depending on your version, this might be an interesting answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22833767/10608418

Comment: this is actually beautiful, i don't know how i missed it, thanks a lot! @Knoop

Comment: No problem, good luck with your project!

Comment: If Knoop helped you out, you should have given him an upvote, like I did. He delivered a useful comment, didn't he?

Comment: @qqtf  believe me i'd love to, unfortunately i don't have the reputation yet

Comment: my mistake. I guess I fixed that than. Take care & good luck

Answer (score 0):

Fluent Validation.
A popular .NET library for building strongly-typed validation rules.
Checkout this and hope this will resolve your problem.

Comment: What OP is asking for is different from validation. `HasPrecision` is used so entity framework knows what data type to give to the column in whatever database is used behind it.

Answer (score 0):

EF allows you to inherit from `EntityTypeConfiguration` and use it to make your own configurations for each entity. Then add the `EntityTypeConfiguration-derived` class to the fluent set.

For example: book configuration class

```
public class BookConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Book>
{
   public BookConfig()
   {
      Property(p => p.bookNo).HasPrecision(18, 2);
      Property(p => p.BookPrice).HasPrecision(18, 2);
   }
}
```

Now introduce it to the fluent library

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
   modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new BookConfig());
}
```