# .NET decimal value cause SqlTruncateException on SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have a .NET app that sends a table-valued parameter to a SQL Server stored procedure.

In the SQL Server table, the column is defined as `DECIMAL(20,0)`.

Table-valued column on .NET defined as

```
Columns.Add(new SqlMetaData(name, SqlDbType.Decimal));
```

When sending a 20 or 19 digit long .net `decimal` value like this `Convert.ToDecimal(81210694789319013214)`, SQL Server throws an exception:

> SqlTruncateException: Numeric arithmetic causes truncation

On a 18 digits long decimal, it works just fine.

There's not much documentation about this error online.

Thanks

Comment: Can't repro - works just fine, both in SSMS and from a .NET 4.8.1 / ADO.NET code snippet. You need to **show us** just **HOW** you do the insert operation! What does your stored procedure look like? How are you calling it  from C#?

Comment: This question is not answerable without relevant code

Comment: found the issue.
On table valued parameter had to write like this      
Columns.Add(new SqlMetaData(name, SqlDbType.Decimal, 20, 0));
instead of Columns.Add(new SqlMetaData(name, SqlDbType.Decimal));

Answer (score 0):

You haven't showed us any code - so this is **purely speculative**. But just maybe, check your stored procedure parameter for the decimal value - how is it defined?

Did you just use `DECIMAL` without providing any precision and scale values?

If so: `DECIMAL` defaults to `DECIMAL(18,0)` - which would explain why it works with 18 digit numbers, but not with 20 digits.

You need to **explicitly** define the precision and scale to use - Best Practice is to do this ***ALWAYS*** anyway!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertDecimal
    @InputDecimal DECIMAL(20,0)     -- define 20 digits, 0 after decimal point
AS
  .....
```

With this - everything should work **just fine** ....

The [official Microsoft documentation on `DECIMAL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) will tell you more details

Comment: As I mentioned on DB the type is already DECIMAL(20,0) but from .NET app value is sent as
Convert.ToDecimal(field.Value)

Comment: In your C# code, you should use a **properly parametrized** query, and you should use a `SqlParameter` - something like this: `cmdYourSqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@InputDecimal", SqlDbType.Decimal, 20).Value = (your value here)` - then everything works fine - don't use strings and convert and stuff like that ....

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EF

Set DecimalPropertyConfiguration.HasPrecision Method as per the link
[Decimal precision and scale in EF Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504660/decimal-precision-and-scale-in-ef-code-first)